# Send email after term is selected in checkbox in a node form with rules

Tags: taxonomy-terms, rules, emails, nodes

I have created a node form which has taxonomy vocabulary Application Status with three terms  represented as check boxes

Approve Masters 
Approve Honours 
Rejected

What I am trying to achieve is when you select one of the terms a unique rule for each term sends an email for the term that has been selected in the check box.
I have tried numerous setups but cannot get it to work properly. My current approach is

Event:

After updating existing content of type Online Application Form

After saving a new field collection item

Conditions :

Entity is new

Actions:

Send HTML e-mail

If anybody can give me some good advice on how to achieve this I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need:

- An "Entity has field" condition to check for the existence of the taxonomy field, and then
- A "Data comparison" condition to match the value of the taxonomy field to the one of the three terms on which you want the rule to operate.

You have two Events in your rule. It seems if you put the Field Collection condition first, then the node fields aren't available in Rules, and vice-versa. So list the "After updating existing content of type Online Application Form" event first so that you can access the taxonomy field in the conditions.